# How to add application logo when users use Android app to post to Facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

How do I add a logo when users use my Android app to post to their Facebook wall?

For example, when I post from TweetDeck, their icon appears like this...

[image: TweetDeck icon appears below post]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure when you create facebook application same as TweetDeck, at that time you have to provide a application logo like Black sparrow shown in above image, and it will appear when you post to your facebook wall from your android application.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't do it when I created the app as I hadn't finished my logo design.  To add the image go to you Facebook app choose "Settings" > Basic.  You are then ablle to add an icon and a profile picture.